# how is it possible that the output of two commands differs, one being symlink of the other?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

One executable file is symlink of another:

```
#ls -l /sbin/depmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Mar 15 07:00 /sbin/depmod -> ../bin/kmod
```

Then why is this:

```
#/sbin/depmod 
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.10.0-693.5.2.el7.x86_64: No such file or directory
```

(...)

```
#/bin/kmod
missing command
```

(...)

Comment: Maybe the command searches for a file in a relative directory? Or it inspects `$0`, i.e. its behaviour depends on how you called it?

Comment: Yes probably checks its name, thank you, please make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be several reasons.

For example, the command might search for the file in a directory relative to its own location.

Another possibility is that the behaviour of the command depends on what its name is (e.g. a shell script could check $0).